# C# | Не работает вычисление из числа число

Tags: c#, алгоритм, .net-5

У меня есть код, в котором объявлен словарь. Ключ - название кофе, а значение - его цена. Я написал этот словарь, и дальше, мне нужно запросить у пользователя число, которое будет как скидка. Я должен вывести в консоль цены этих кофе со скидкой в таком шаблоне: `Key: {Value with discount}`. Я написал в цикле `foreach` вывод с каждой строки мой шаблон. Я добавил в значение немного математики. Но мне выводит цену: либо стандартную, либо "0". Помогите пожалуйста, вот мой код:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static int ComputeDiscount(int originalNumber, int discount)
        {
            return originalNumber - (originalNumber / 100 * discount);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            dict.Add("Americano", 50);
            dict.Add("Latte", 70);
            dict.Add("Flat White", 60);
            dict.Add("Espresso", 60);
            dict.Add("Cappuccino", 80);
            dict.Add("Mocha", 90);

            var discount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            foreach (var item in dict)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}: {Convert.ToInt32(item.Value) - (item.Value / 100 * discount)}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Замените `100` на `100.0`.

Comment: Поясню предыдущий комментарий - у вас получается целочисленное деление, поэтому и выходит `0` при делении целого числа на `100`. А вот если делить на `100.0`, то деление уже будет как для чисел с плавающей точкой.

Comment: Кстати, можно ещё поменять местами деление и умножение, тогда можно и целыми числами обойтись: `item.Value * discount / 100 `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
item.Value / 100 * discount
```

Поскольку все участвующие в выражении числа у вас целые, в результате деления на `100` числа, которое меньше `100`, всегда получается `0`. И дальше уже без толку этот ноль на что-то умножать, всё-равно будет ноль.

Можно поменять местами умножение и сложение:

```
item.Value * discount / 100
```

Так у вас что-то получится в итоге, но с точностью до рублей, копеек не будет. Если надо с точностью до копеек, то нужно переходить к арифметике с плавающей точкой, например, так, как предложил VladD, прямо указав, что мы делим на число с плавающей точкой `100.0`:

```
item.Value / 100.0 * discount
```

Comment: А, ну по-сути да, если моя цена будет 100Р, то если я проверю скидку `50 / 100 * discount`, то да, будет 0.5, а у меня тип `Integer`.